# Как исправить ошибку? Ошибка возникает при Update-database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef

Ошибка возникает при Update-database:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Comments_Posts_PostId". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Posts", column 'Id'.

The statement has been terminated.

Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns]
  WHERE [name] IN (N'Id', N'DislikeCount', N'ImageUrl', N'LikeCount', N'PostId', N'PostStatisticsId', N'Text', N'UserId')
    AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Comments]')
)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Comments] ON;

INSERT INTO [Comments]
([Id], [DislikeCount], [ImageUrl], [LikeCount], [PostId], [PostStatisticsId], [Text], [UserId])
VALUES
  (18, 3, NULL, 15, 32, 0, N'Private companies and government agencies both have roles in space exploration.', 33),
  (19, 2, NULL, 17, 33, 0, N'Telemedicine is making healthcare more accessible to remote areas.', 34);

IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns]
  WHERE [name] IN (N'Id', N'DislikeCount', N'ImageUrl', N'LikeCount', N'PostId', N'PostStatisticsId', N'Text', N'UserId') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Comments]')
)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Comments] OFF;
```

Буду очень благодарна за помощь

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOne(u => u.PostStatistics)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.PostStatisticsId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Posts)
                .WithOne(p => p.User)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Comments)
                .WithOne(c => c.User)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<TopicOfPost>()
                .HasMany(tp => tp.Posts)
                .WithOne(p => p.Topic)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.TopicOfPostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.PostStatistics)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Post>(p => p.PostStatisticsId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Topic)
                .WithMany(t => t.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.TopicOfPostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Categories)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Comments)
                .WithOne(c => c.Post)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.PostStatistics)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Comment>(c => c.PostStatisticsId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Posts)
                .WithOne(p => p.Categories)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);


 public class PostStatistics
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "LikeCount must be a non-negative number.")]
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "DislikeCount must be a non-negative number.")]
        public int DislikeCount { get; set; }
    }
 public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Title' field is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Title must be between 3 and 100 characters.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Text' field is required.")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
 
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Image URL cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
 
        public int PostStatisticsId { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("PostStatisticsId")]
        public PostStatistics PostStatistics { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
 
        public int TopicOfPostId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TopicOfPostId")]
        public TopicOfPost Topic { get; set; }
 
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
 
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Categories { get; set; }
    }
public class CommonFields
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string VisibilityStatus { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Image URL cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Text' field is required.")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Image URL cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "LikeCount must be a non-negative number.")]
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "DislikeCount must be a non-negative number.")]
        public int DislikeCount { get; set; }
 
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
 
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PostId")]
        public Post Post { get; set; }
 
        public int PostStatisticsId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PostStatisticsId")]
        public PostStatistics PostStatistics { get; set; }
    }
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
 
        public int AmountOfTopics { get; set; }
 
        [Required]
        public string VisibilityStatus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
public class TopicOfPost
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Name' field is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be between 3 and 100 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
 
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
 
        // Active, Suspended
        public string VisibilityStatus { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
 
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field 'Username' is required")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Username must Post between 3 and 50 characters")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field 'Password' is required")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must Post between 8 and 50 characters")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Image URL cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
 
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
 
        public int PostStatisticsId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PostStatisticsId")]
        public PostStatistics PostStatistics { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нету такого значения `0` у `Id` в таблице сущностей `PostStatistics`:

```
INSERT INTO [Comments]
([Id], [DislikeCount], [ImageUrl], [LikeCount], [PostId], [PostStatisticsId], [Text], [UserId])
                                               >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ^ <<<<<<<<<<<<
VALUES
  (18, 3, NULL, 15, 32, 0, N'Private companies and government agencies both have roles in space exploration.', 33),
  (19, 2, NULL, 17, 33, 0, N'Telemedicine is making healthcare more accessible to remote areas.', 34);
          >>>>>>>>>>>>> ^ <<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Ну как, разобрадись?